# Asp.Net Core 2.2 TLS 1.2 support on Azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, tls1.2, azure-web-app-service

We're running our applications (web api's) on .net core 2.2 in-process mode on Azure app service.
We have 3rd party dependencies that require TLS 1.2 only (outbound http calls). Would calls from our service support tls 1.2 out of the box or do we have to enable anything like ServicePointManager or anything similar for HttpClient or the HttpClientFactory?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did testing on Azure and it seems you don't have to configure anything at all as the latest version available on the host machine will be picked up. We hosted another API for which we enabled TLS 1.2 only and made a call from our API to the other one.
Worth noting that the setting on app service for TLS version is only for INBOUND connections, not OUTBOUND.
.Net Core 2.2, in-process mode, hosted on Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use framework-specific settings to force outbound calls to use TLS 1.2. Based on .NET Core docs, would need to explicitly create and configure an instance of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=netcore-2.2, configuring the SslOptions property on the object to only allow TLS 1.2, then instantiate an instance of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-2.2 passing in the SocketsHttpHandler instance that has been configured to require TLS 1.2.